# Function injective but not surjective

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given an example of mapping $f:S\to S$ which is *one-to-one* but not *onto*.

Let's take $S=\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)=e^x$ then it is clear that this function is injective but not onto.

Can anyone also give another example?

Answer (score 3):

Take $S = \mathbb{N}$ and $f(n) = n+1$.

Comment: Nice and easy example in order to remember. What about onto but not one-to-one?

Comment: @Arthur Sorry, I was editing as the same time as you.

Comment: @RFZ Same set, with "Subtract one, except for $0$, which stays at $0$" (assuming $0\in \Bbb N$ for you).

Answer (score 2):

The successor function $s: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}: n \mapsto n+1$

is injective but not surjective.

If you want an example of a non-injective, but surjective function, you can consider:

$f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}: n \mapsto \begin{cases}1 &\text{if }n<3 \\n-1 &\text{if } n \geq 3\end{cases}$

Note that you must always take an infinite set for $S$, because for a finite set $S$ we have:

$f: S \to S$ injective $\iff$ $f: S \to S$ surjective

Comment: In your second example $f(1)=0 \notin \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Ah I assumed that $0 \in \mathbb{N}$. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: That's much better

Comment: Here you go. It is not injective because f(1) = f(2) = 1 but obviously it is surjective. Because let $n$ be a natural number, then $f(n+1) = n$

Comment: Good example. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome!